# Dynamic data-title with ng-repeat in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm looking for a solution to show dynamic header in the angular table for some of its `<td>`
my data looks like

```
let data = [    
    {
    id: 1,
    name: 'name',
    fields: {
    field 1: { value: '123'},
    field 2: {value: 'macx'}
    }
    },
    {
    id: 2,
    name: 'name2',
    fields: {
    field 1: { value: '456'},
    field 2: {value: '3333'}
    }
    }
]
```

it should show in one table, I mean fields attr's should show as extra columns in the same table
note: fields are dynamic and I can't know it exactly so I need to do something like this in code
if any idea how I can get that work or any other idea to get the view as explained

```html
<tr ng-repeat="data in $data">
    <td data-title="'id'|translate"
        sortable="'id'">
    {{data.id}}
    </td>
    <td ng-repeat="(key, value) in data.fields track by $index"
        ng-show="columnsHash[key]"
        data-title="customFieldsTitles[$index]"
        filterable="{field:'fields', type:'text', align:'LEFT'}"
        data-title-text="customFieldsTitles[$index]">
      {{value && value.value || ''}}
    </td>
    <td ng-show="columnsHash.totalBenefitTarget"
        data-title="'target_total_benefit' | translate"
        sortable="'total_benefit_target'"
        style="text-align:center;"
        filterable="{field: 'total_benefit_target', type:'number_range', options: {min:  Number.MIN_VALUE, max: Number.MAX_VALUE}}">
      {{data.total_benefit_target | number: 0}}
    </td>
    <td ng-show="columnsHash.totalBenefitActual"
        data-title="'actual_total_benefit' | translate"
        sortable="'total_benefit_actual'"
        style="text-align:center;"
        filterable="{field: 'total_benefit_actual', type:'number_range',
        options: {min:  Number.MIN_VALUE, max: Number.MAX_VALUE}}">
      {{data.total_benefit_actual | number: 0}}
    </td>
<tr>
```

showing columns order is important so writing it like code above
thanks in advance

Comment: `[data-title]="expression"` will make angular treat the "value" as an expression and compute what it should actually be.  Or at least it will in current day angular.  I'm not 100% if that behavior existed in 1x

Comment: i m using angular 1x angular-table module
my concerns that it load  table header first so it not create th tag for dynamic td

Comment: What did you try and what problems did you have with that attempt.

Comment: In Angular 1.6 we use interpolation e.g. `data-title="{{expression}}"`. Anyway json you posted is malformed and no minimum reproducible example provided.

Comment: @georgeawg @Daniel Manta 
i tried `data-title="{{expression}}"` it getting 

`Syntax Error: Token '{' invalid key at column 2 of the expression [{{key}}] starting at [{key}}].`
and i tried to get all key and set it into list and get it directly as in above code and no syntac error also it not load th for these tds at all seems it load header first thing and it not updated after that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
angular table use scope.$column to render tb cols so I solved that by using scope binding 
<table ng-table="tableParams" ng-init="initTable()">
<td ng-repeat="(key, value) in data.fields"
                data-title="'Custom Field'"
                sortable="'fields'"
                filterable="{field:'fields', type:'text', align:'LEFT'}">
              {{value && value.value || ''}}
 </td>
</table>

in controller
    var tableColumns;
    $scope.initTable = function(){
      var scope = this;
      $timeout(function(){
        tableColumns = scope.$columns;
      });
    };
    after loading data for table call this function to update columns title
     function updateCustomFields(){
      var columnTemplate, index;
      var colCount = 0;
      if (!tableColumns) {
        return;
      }
      tableColumns.map(function(col, i){
        if (col.title() === 'Custom Field'){
          columnTemplate = col;
          index = i;
          tableColumns.splice(index, 1);
          return true;
        }
      });
      for(var fieldLabel in $scope.customFieldsHash){
        (function (label) {
          var column = angular.copy(columnTemplate);
          column.id = column.id+colCount/10;
          column.title = function(){ return label; };
          tableColumns.splice(index+colCount, 0, column);
          colCount++;
        })(fieldLabel);
      }
    }
```

Comment: Your solution kinda works for me, too. However, I can't seem to get the sort- and filter-mechanisms to work. All fields are linked together and sorting / filtering doesn't work. What does your table data look like? Could you provide a complete working example?